# javascript - event.defaultPrevented never true

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to use events in my script, but it seems I don't understand how event.preventDefault()/event.defaultPrevented work :

```
var e = new Event('test');

e.defaultPrevented;
> false

e.preventDefault();

e.defaultPrevented;
> false
```

How do I set `e.defaultPrevented` to `true` ?
It behave the same way in Chrome/Firefox/Edge so I must do something wrong.

Thank you :)

**EDIT :** The issue was that I forgot to create Event with :

```
var e = new Event('test', {cancelable: true});
```

Comment: I don’t think calling `preventDefault` they way you are trying it there makes much sense to begin with. This should happen inside the event handler callback function - which you don’t even have here. Check out the example under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented, that should help making things a bit clearer, I think.

Comment: @mplungjan that’s jQuery? Then `e` is not a native event instance, but a https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ And that appears to have an explicit _method_ to check for this, https://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/ If you go with `e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented`, do you get a different result?

Comment: @CBroe thanks - I never realised this. I always treated the event in jQuery the same as a native event and now it the first time I noticed this.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use it like this

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.defaultPrevented)
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.defaultPrevented)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click</a>
```

jQuery has a specific function

```js
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented())
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click</a>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's because click events are cancelable :)